# Access Not Configured Error when connecting to Google Play Serives

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services

I am getting the following error when attempting to connect to Google Play Services:

```
-- E/Volley﹕ [131] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/me?language=en_US
-- E/SignInIntentService﹕ Access Not Configured. Google Play Game Services API has not been used in project 608941808256 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/games/overview?project=608941808256 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
com.google.android.gms.games.server.error.GamesException
```

I have configured my application on Google Play Developer Console and it's ready for testing. I have linked an app to it and enabled appropriate APIs in the Developer Console (Google+ Api, Google Play Services Api, Goole Play Android Developer Api ..).

I used the SHA1 keys that the apk uses, which I added to the OAuth 2.0 list in the Developer Console.

I am using sample code provided by Google, have added my app_id in the ids.xml file (1058015326796), which does **not** match the project ID in the error message.

How do I connect to Google Play Services properly? Have I forgot some step in setting up the access? Why is the project ID in the error message different from the ID I am using in the application?

Answer (score 0):

608941808256 is a telling project ID - it means that for some reason Google Play services didn't map your app to your client ID. This look up is generally performed by SHA1 and package name.

You mention you added your SHA1 to the developer console, which is good - maybe then check that the package name is correct. For example, maybe you append ".dev" to the package name for development builds or similar, or the package name in your build.gradle is different than the one in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apis/credentials).

Remember to look under *OAuth 2.0 client IDs* as well - that's the section that needs to have matching values.

Answer (score 0):

I spend 4 days with the same problem. 
I had created project in Google Play Developer Console with all needed API's
Like you I used the SHA1 keys that the apk uses, which I added to the OAuth 2.0 list in the Developer Console.

**And the solution in my case was :**
to generate signed APK.

I was sending GET request for Account Data with app that was just build and run.
After 4 days of trying i read

> Before you can publish an app that retrieves an OAuth 2.0 token for Google REST APIs, you must register your Android app with the Google Cloud Console by providing your app's package name and the **SHA1 fingerprint of the keystore with which you sign your release APK.**

and thought I will generate signed APK, and it worked.

Ps. I doesn't use Volley so i don't know if this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

- [Problem 1] Wrong app_id, achievement/leaderboard IDs in the ids.xml!
- [Solution 1] Replace or set the ids from google play game console.
- [Problem 2] Use debug key and release key by mistake
- [Solution 2] Be careful using the key(SHA1), pay attention whether it is debug or release.